# MySQL-Proxy works with HeidiSQL but not with DBeaver nor Workbench

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench, dbeaver, heidisql, mysql-proxy

For data analytical applications, our current development environment relies on a MySQL-Proxy (version 0.8) to connect to the MySQL data source. And the MySQL's version is `5.7.43-47-log`.

We noticed that:

- the proxy works OK with `HeidiSQL` (version 9.5.0.5196 64-bit), however,
- it does not work with `DBeaver` (version 23.2.0.202309041200) nor `MySQL Workbench` (version 8.0.28 build 1474738 CE).

When not working, the symptom is that the client can complete password input, but then hangs forever upon opening the connection.

**Our Questions:**

- We hope to understand why the proxy works with some clients but not the others, so that we have more confidence in our development environment.
- Also, please point out if we can make the proxy work with `DBeaver` and/or `MySQL Workbench` as well.

We highly appreciate hints and suggestions.

**Details:**

Please see below the `HeidiSQL` and `MySQL Workbench` connections exported in text format. Please remind us if you know how to export connections to text in DBeaver.

This this test, the `mysql-proxy` runs on `192.168.56.xx:3306`, and it forwards SQL queries to a MySQL server on its backend.

1. The `HeidiSQL` connection:

```
...
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SessionCreated<|||>1<|||>2023-12-13 15:15:20
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Host<|||>1<|||>192.168.56.xx
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\WindowsAuth<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\User<|||>1<|||>sqlv
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Password<|||>1<|||>4*******************5
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\LoginPrompt<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Port<|||>1<|||>3306
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\NetType<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Compressed<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\LocalTimeZone<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\QueryTimeout<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\KeepAlive<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\FullTableStatus<|||>3<|||>1
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Databases<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\Comment<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\StartupScriptFilename<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\TreeBackground<|||>3<|||>536870911
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelHost<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelHostPort<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelUser<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelPassword<|||>1<|||>7
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelTimeout<|||>3<|||>4
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelPrivateKey<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSHtunnelPort<|||>3<|||>3307
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSL_Active<|||>3<|||>0
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSL_Key<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSL_Cert<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSL_CA<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\SSL_Cipher<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\ServerVersionFull<|||>1<|||>5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\ConnectCount<|||>3<|||>2
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\ServerVersion<|||>3<|||>50724
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\LastConnect<|||>1<|||>2023-12-13 15:20:36
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\lastUsedDB<|||>1<|||>
Servers\mysql-proxy\mysql-proxy-test-sqlv\RefusedCount<|||>3<|||>1
...
```

2. The `MySQL Workbench` connection's JDBC string:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.xx:3306/?user=sqlv
```